# How to keep socket alive?

Tags: python

Should i keep alive sockets on my server if I interact with known clients for a long time and all of them stays online and max amount of them is 10?
If yes what the best way to do this? Something like:

```
class mysocket:
    '''demonstration class only
      - coded for clarity, not efficiency
    '''

    def __init__(self, sock=None):
        if sock is None:
            self.sock = socket.socket(
                socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        else:
            self.sock = sock

    def connect(self, host, port):
        self.sock.connect((host, port))

    def mysend(self, msg):
        totalsent = 0
        while totalsent < MSGLEN:
            sent = self.sock.send(msg[totalsent:])
            if sent == 0:
                raise RuntimeError("socket connection broken")
            totalsent = totalsent + sent

    def myreceive(self):
        chunks = []
        bytes_recd = 0
        while bytes_recd < MSGLEN:
            chunk = self.sock.recv(min(MSGLEN - bytes_recd, 2048))
            if chunk == '':
                raise RuntimeError("socket connection broken")
            chunks.append(chunk)
            bytes_recd = bytes_recd + len(chunk)
        return ''.join(chunks)
```

will be good?
Also what happens if I specify more size for recv() then socket have?

Comment: Is the "interaction" constant/frequent, or is it a few packets once a day? The answer to that might indicate whether you should keep a single long-lived connection, or utilize multiple short-lived connections...

Comment: @twalberg, frequent. Can be ~500-1000 packets per minute.